# Validate ActiveRecord models have same association / group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So I am trying to get my head around a custom validation on two ActiveRecord models. The application I am working on contains 3 models; a note, a writer and a notebook. Whenever I create a note through a form, I want to validate that it has the exact same notebook as the writer is currently allowed to work on when created or updated.

The models look really simplified like this;

```
class Notebook < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :notes
   has_many :writers
end

class Writer < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :notes
   belongs_to: notebook
end

class Note < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to: writer
   belongs_to: notebook
end
```

So whenever I do something like this;

```
another_notebook = Notebook.new

writer = Writer.new

note = Note.new(writer: writer, notebook: another_notebook)
note.save!
```

A validation error is thrown as the writer and the notebook do not have an association with each other.

Comment: can you add the error message please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just start off by creating indirect assocations:

```
class Notebook < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :notes
   has_many :writers, through: :notes
end

class Note < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to: writer
   belongs_to: notebook
end

class Writer < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :notes
   has_many :notebooks, through: :notes
   # ...
end
```

This creates a many-to-many association between Notebook and Writer.

If you then want to add rule that the `writer` can only create notes in a specific notebook:

```
class Writer < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :notes
   has_many :notebooks, through: :notes
   belongs_to :current_notebook, class: 'Notebook'
end

class Note < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  validate :is_current_notebook

  def is_current_notebook
    unless notebook == writer.current_notebook
      errors.add(:notebook, 'is not valid.')
    end
  end
end
```

However I would consider if this actually is a good fit for a model validation as it seems like more of a authorization issue that should be handled by CanCanCan or Pundit and not an issue of bad user input which is what validations should handle.

Comment: Thanks Max for the answer! Exactly what I was looking for! I can see how you say that it is more of an authorization issue, but I would like to constraint that people cannot create different notes for different notebooks by changing the parameters in the URL (/:notebook_id/notes/:note_id/edit).

Comment: They should not be able to do that anyways if you set the controller up properly.